# Regex to replace an Nth+ occurrences

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a string like:

```
AAA|BBBB|CCCCCC|DDD|EEE|FFF
```

I need a regex to replace all pipes after the third pipe with an exclamation mark `!`, like this:

```
AAA|BBBB|CCCCCC|DDD!EEE!FFF
```

I could select with `^(?:[^|^\n]*\|){3}([^|^\n]*\|){1,}.*$` but could not find a way to replace.

I tried with Notepad++.

Comment: A day? Then please show what you tried. I am sure there is something that worked at least a bit. This will help us understand your intentions better and help you find a solution quicker.

Comment: You can do this in Notepad++ only if the substrings like `AAA` has fixed length (e.g. "3").

Comment: @horcrux: No, it is easy to do without that restriction.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well, not a day, but a few hours that I spent there... I could select with ^(?:[^|^\n]*\|){3}([^|^\n]*\|){1,}.*$ but could not find a way to replace

Comment: @horcrux No, Strings are of different length in reality -  sorry ! I edited my example to show that.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track just need to match and capture other pipes in an alternation.

Find what:

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){3}\K|(\|)
```

Replace with:

```
(?1!)
```

Replacement string follows a conditional statement which means if we are going to replace on capturing group #1, insert a `!`.

Comment: \K? Oooh. http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html Huh, I learned a thing today! Mind you, I wish they'd just enable variable-width lookbehind, instead of slathering their engines with kludgy escape characters.

Comment: If it answers your question please click on the check mark beside the answer to accept it. Also you may want to up-vote it if you found the solution nice and neat by using the up arrow. @monam

Comment: We look for it too. @DewiMorgan

Comment: I didn't know you can use a conditional statement in the replacement  field with notepad++.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: See [this Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html)